# How can I remove one collection in my Jekyll page during development?

Tags: jekyll

In my Jekyll page I have huge collections that take 35s to render and sometimes I just delete the biggest folders to iterate faster but I figure it should also be possible to have a secondary `_config.dev.yml` that undoes the `_config.yml`'s collection definition. But I fail to get it to work.

How do I get jekyll to disregard a folder that is configured for a collection in `_config.yml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have Jekyll pretend folders to be empty, simply [`exclude`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/) these folders in your `_config.dev.yml`:

```
exclude:
  - _bigCollection
  - _otherBigCollection
```

Comment: Or you could set `output: false` for that collection? See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#output

Comment: I had tried that out but it did not work. Also as the 4k pages are substantial but the data also flows into another 8s of list generation, it would be the inferior solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the other way round:

1. Do *not* define the collection in `_config.yml`.
2. When you deploy your site to production (or when you *do* want to render the big collections locally), use a secondary `_config_with_collections.yml` which includes just the collection definitions.